# I can't make the outer glow for the moon

Tags: shaders, color, compositing-nodes, effects

I made this moon and I'm trying to give it an outer glow and also I would like to have emission, but the texture to be visible. Can you guys help me? I'm attaching the render and some stock photos for what I would like to achieve. The final image is the render, I'm trying to achieve something similar to the last reference photo.

[image: Light_bounce]
[image: Emission]
[image: Light_bounce2]
[image: Moon_light]
[image: Outer_glow]
[image: Render]

I also add the shading nodes and the compositor nodes. I want to add emission to the object, but I can't get it right, I want the texture to be visible, but the object to emit light, to be the main light source for my scene. If I add emission shader, I can't see the details like craters and bumps from the moon. Can you guys please help me?

[image: Shading_nodes]
[image: Compositor_nodes]

Comment: about the outer glow: it's only in the second ref image because of the earth's atmosphere it's being seen through (you could do that with a glare node). The last ref image is of a planet with it's own atmosphere, but the moon doesn't have one so it would look different

Comment: You mean you want an atmospheric glow? Or do you want the whole moon to cast a "corona"?

Comment: I want an atmospheric glow just like the earth reference photo and I want the moon to emit light, but the details to remain visible, if I add an emission shader, the whole object turns yellow/white. I tried with another sphere with a principled volume and a density of 0.2 and in compositor to add a glare node, but it doesn't look like the image with the earth.

Comment: Hello :). Eevee has a nice *Bloom* option that gives a similar result (a glow around emmisive objects).

Comment: Hello, I'm using Cycles, I know about Eevee bloom, but I'm trying to achieve it in Cycles for final rendering.